# Using two SELECT queries in php database connection

Tags: php, mysql

here is `my_sqli` database connection

```
class FbChatMock {
    // Holds the database connection
    private $dbConnection;
    private $_dbHost = 'localhost';
    private $_dbUsername = 'root';
    private $_dbPassword = '';
    public $_databaseName = 'erp5_temp2';
    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbConnection = new mysqli($this->_dbHost, $this->_dbUsername, 
            $this->_dbPassword, $this->_databaseName); 
        if ($this->dbConnection->connect_error) {
            die('Connection error.');
        }
    }
```

i am getting two parameters in the `getchat` function:

```
public function getchat($userId, $id){ 
    $meesage = array();

    $query = "SELECT u.user_id FROM  `users` u where u.id='$id'";
    $resultObj = $this->dbConnection->query($query);
    $user = $resultObj->fetch_assoc())
    $userid = $user;
}
```

I am getting the `$userid` variable from the query and using it inside this query:

```
$query = "SELECT u.id,c.message,c.sent_on FROM `chat` c JOIN 
    `users` u ON c.user_id=u.user_id where u.id='$id' AND c.user_id='$userid'";
     // Execute the query
     $resultObj = $this->dbConnection->query($query);
     // Fetch all the rows at once.
     while ($rows = $resultObj->fetch_assoc()){
         $meesage[] = $rows;
     }
     return $meesage;
```

And the problem is that my first sql query is not working correctly . i have tested it by showing `$userid` value from echo.

Answer (score 3):

Chage this line

```
$userid = $user;
```

To this

```
$userid = $user['user_id'];
```

Because $user it is array with all columns you have selected, and you need get only ID from it.

Comment: i change the  line by this  $userid = $user['user_id'];
    echo ($userid);
    exit(); but it is not showing echo result

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here :

```
$user = $resultObj->fetch_assoc())
$userid = $user;
```

because [`mysqli::fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) with retrieve an associative array. Thus you have to access it like so (given the column name in your select):

```
$userid = $user["user_id"];
```

Comment: i changed line by this  $userid = $user['user_id'];
    echo ($userid);
    exit(); but it is not showing echo result

Comment: try to `var_dump()` it and see what it tells you